# Copy Table Constraints/Keys along with Data and Structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table "TableA", I want to make a copy of it "TableA_Copy", when I use the below script, it creates Table and data, but Constraints are not copied, is it possible copy the constraints along with Structure and Data

```
SELECT * INTO TableA_Copy FROM TableA
```

Note am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: you can script tableA, change objects names replacing `TableA` with `TableA_Copy`, run the script to create the new one and then fill it with data

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on the database and go to tasks->Generate script.
2. Select the table you want TableA, go to next step and ynder advanced options select data and schema.
3. Save the script or have it in a new query window.
4. Once the script is generated, replace TableA with TableA_copy

This way you will get data, schema and all the constraints. Remember to change the name of constraints to avoid any errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean programmatically, then yes there are a number of ways in tsql to accomplish this by using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. The particular ones you will need for the table/columns are INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. For the constraints you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE which will provide you the PK and FKs and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS for all check constraints.

Using these you can rebuild the table, complete, for use as you indicate above.